# A good source for lisp libraries?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there a PEAR kind library for lisp?  I hope there is, but I read somewhere that one of the disadvantages of lisp is its lack of serious libraries.  I find that hard to believe since lisp is half a century old now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Common Lisp Wiki](http://www.cliki.net/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried quicklisp?

http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/

Comment: This is a good answer. Quicklisp makes the access to many hundred libraries easy.

Answer (score 3):

As jlf said www.cliki.net is a good starting point. Also take a closer look at **asdf-install** and **clbuild**. If you are on linux clbuild is like package manager for lisp libraries.

Answer (score 3):

[common-lisp.net](http://common-lisp.net/projects.shtml) hosts a lot of Lisp projects. Many are installable via ASDF.

See also [The Common Lisp Directory](http://www.cl-user.net/).

Answer (score 1):

[Mudballs](http://mudballs.com) is also worth a look.

Comment: It looks like this url is invalid; and I seem to recall the creator of Mudballs posting sometime last year that he was no longer going to work on it due to time constraints?

Comment: The project was still active in 2009, when I posted this. The sources for Mudballs are available at http://github.com/sross/mudballs

Answer (score 1):

It's a myth that there's a lack of libraries for CL.

I can recommend clbuild to manage your libraries.

Use cl-user.net to find specific libraries.